# Discord Python Bot Error Message client.command

Tags: python, discord.py

I've tried modifying the client value, but I am still getting the same error, which is attached below.

This is the code for a weather discord bot:

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
from discord.ext import commands
client = discord.Client() 


api_key = "12345"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"


@client.command()
async def weather(ctx, *, city: str):

        city_name = city
        complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
        response = requests.get(complete_url)
        x = response.json()
        channel = ctx.message.channel

        if x["cod"] != "404":

                y = x["main"]
                current_temperature = y["temp"]
                current_temperature_celsiuis = str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
                current_pressure = y["pressure"]
                current_humidity = y["humidity"]
                z = x["weather"]
                weather_description = z[0]["description"]

                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f"Weather forecast - {city_name}",
                    color=0x7289DA,
                    timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
                )
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Description",
                    value=f"**{weather_description}**",
                    inline=False)
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Temperature(C)",
                    value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**",
                    inline=False)
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Humidity(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Atmospheric Pressure(hPa)",
                    value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**",
                    inline=False)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")

                await channel.send(embed=embed)

        else:
                await channel.send(
                    f"There was no results about this place!")
client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 135, in <module>
    @client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'
```

New to discord bots. I am unable to fix this issue.

Any feedback would be appreciated...........................

Comment: Use something like `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')` instead of `client = discord.Client()`

Answer (score 0):

write something like that: `client = command.Bot(command_prefix="!")` instade of `client = discord.Client()`

````
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
from discord.ext import commands


client = command.Bot(command_prefix="!")


api_key = "12345"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"


@client.command()
async def weather(ctx, *, city: str):

        city_name = city
        complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
        response = requests.get(complete_url)
        x = response.json()
        channel = ctx.message.channel

        if x["cod"] != "404":

                y = x["main"]
                current_temperature = y["temp"]
                current_temperature_celsiuis = str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
                current_pressure = y["pressure"]
                current_humidity = y["humidity"]
                z = x["weather"]
                weather_description = z[0]["description"]

                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f"Weather forecast - {city_name}",
                    color=0x7289DA,
                    timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
                )
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Description",
                    value=f"**{weather_description}**",
                    inline=False)
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Temperature(C)",
                    value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**",
                    inline=False)
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Humidity(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(
                    name="Atmospheric Pressure(hPa)",
                    value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**",
                    inline=False)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")

                await channel.send(embed=embed)

        else:
                await channel.send(
                    f"There was no results about this place!")
client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])```
````